# Converting NULL string columns from flat file source to DATETIME and INT types in destination table

Tags: ssis

I am importing a flat file source to a table, all my flat file columns are string datatype. And few of my columns are NULL values, whereas in my destination tables those are Datetime and Int type. I tried to use derived column and Data conversion transformation but failed to load.

my source columns

```
todaysdate   yesterdaydate   batchno    
NULL           NULL             NULL
```

The `todaysdate` column and `yesterdaydate` column in the destination table are Datetime and the `Batchno` column is an int type. I tried using derived and data conversion transformations but it is failing.

I need to load Null values into destination for this columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the issue,

i have added the following expression in derived column transformation

i replaced todaysdate column in derived column transformation as

**TRIM(todaysDate) =="NULL" ? (DT_STR,20,1252)NULL(DT_STR,20,1252) : todaysdate**